# ASP .NET Core MVC : problem with uploading images

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have images in folder `/wwwroot/upload`.

When I run my application on some pages I can see images on others I can see just crashed ones.

These are example GET methods after typing F12:

```
GET http://localhost:55975/Article/Edit/upload/7d69d935-0ab6-4e82-878f-c19595889004_marynarka.jpg
```

> 404 (Not Found)

```
GET http://localhost:55975/upload/45d9754e-d7e6-4f97-9653-2746304d5b1e_spodnie.jpg
```

> 200 OK (from disk cache)

```
GET http://localhost:55975/Article/Details/upload/297aa78a-64b1-454a-aa26-04eab0897511_szafa.jpg
```

> 404 (Not Found)

**Edit:**

In my code I have `ArticleController` and inside it are `Details` and `Edit` methods.

**Edit.cshtml:**

```
@model Shop.Models.Article
...
<img src="@(Model.Image)"/>
...
```

**Details.cshtml:**

```
@model Shop.Models.Article
...
<img src="@(Model.Image)"/>
...
```

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Shop.Models.Article>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
      <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="@(item.Image)" width="70px" height = "70px"/>
          </td>
      </tr>
```

**Part of CreateArticle method:**

```
if(image != null)
            {
                string uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(image.FileName);
                var name = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + @"\upload", uniqueName);
                image.CopyTo(new FileStream(name, FileMode.Create));
                article.Image = "upload/" + uniqueName;
            }
            if(image == null)
            {
                article.Image = "noimage/NoImage.png";
            }
```

Comment: If it comes back as a 404 then they are simply not there. I see your OK response comes directly from the "uploads" folder but in the others you are somewhere in "Article". I can't tell what is right or wrong without more context.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have ArticleController and inside it are Details and Edit methods.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have just uploaded my post

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your image source attribute. When the image source is set to "uploads/imagename...", you are telling the browser to look for the uploads folder *inside* the current URL path (a "relative" path). That is why some of your image requests are looking for the uploads folder inside your controller route (e.g., /Article/Edit/uploads...).

Instead, set your image source in your view to "/uploads/..." to ensure that the uploads folder path is correct regardless of which controller or URL is used to get the page.

You can learn more about specifying paths [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference the static files in `/wwwroot/upload`.You can try to use `src="~/{folder name in wwwroot}/{image name}"`,such as:

```
<img src="~/upload/xxx.png" width="70px" height = "70px"/>
```

You can refer to the [offcial doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0#serve-static-files) about static files in .net core.